# Cross database query using database name between shard and master db is not working in sql azure with sharding

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, sharding, cross-database

I have sharding in SQL Azure.

Basically my structure is like below: 
1. Master Database 
2. Shard0 
3. Shard1

I store all non sharded client into master database but on special request from client, i create seperate shard from them.

While reporting sometimes i need to access master database data from say Shard0.

I have followed all articles available on internet like https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-vertical-partitioning/

but somehow the [database].[dbo].[tablename] query is not working.

I am using SQL v12 in azure.

Comment: Even I have tried this http://www.scarydba.com/2016/03/21/cross-database-queries-in-azure-sql-database/

Comment: The above link is working because it has different table names in different database while in my scenario have same set of tables in master, shard0, shard1... shardn. So when i try to create external table in shard0 it will says that object is already exists because the table name are same and it is present in each database.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use three part name syntax like above to refer to an external table. You query an external table as if it were a normal local table, i.e., use [schema_name].[external_table_name].

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Torsten